# bcp Logon error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, bcp

I continually get a logon error no matter which logon I use or from what tool I approach this (shell/sqlsms)

```
output
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
SQLState = 42000, NativeError = 4060
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Cannot open database "DispositionTesting" requested by the login. The login failed.
NULL

(5 row(s) affected)
```

I have logon authority owner read write, I've tried multiple logons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database "DispositionTesting" used does not exist, most likely, and you are specifying this on the bcp command line so every login used will fail.

The first error is misleading...